# XPath query to get nth instance of an element

Tags: xml, xpath

There is an HTML file (whose contents I do not control) that has several `input` elements all with the same fixed `id` attribute of `"search_query"`. The contents of the file can change, but I know that I always want to get the second `input` element with the id attribute `"search_query"`.

I need an XPath expression to do this. I tried `//input[@id="search_query"][2]` but that does not work. Here is an example XML string where this query failed:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <input id="search_query" />
   </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form>
    <input id="search_query" />
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form>
    <input id="search_query" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that that the above is merely an example and the other HTML code can be quite different and the `input` elements can appear anywhere with no consistent document structure (except that I am guaranteed there will always be at least two `input` elements with an id attribute of `"search_query"`).

What is the correct XPath expression?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete explanation of the problem and for the wanted solution.

Comment: Minor point: you should never have more than one element with a given ID (and so the HTML in the question is actually invalid).  In practice, browsers will let you do it anyway, but if you do you're missing out on the only benefit of using IDs, which is that they signal "I'm unique" (whereas classes are designed to be used for non-unique signifiers).

Comment: Not a minor point @machineghost ! It is actually a bug! ID stands for unique identifier!

Answer (score 359, accepted):

**This is a FAQ**:

`//somexpression[$N]`

means "Find every node selected by `//somexpression` that is the `$N`th child of its parent".

**What you want is**:

```
(//input[@id="search_query"])[2]
```

**Remember**:  The `[]` operator has higher precedence (priority) than the `//` abbreviation.

Comment: I like this answer. I had not considered a precedence issue (I just assumed simple left-to-right precedence).

Comment: @rlandster: The word "precedence" may be confusing. The unabbreviated form of `//input[@id='search_query'][2]` is: `/descendat-or-self::node()/child::input[attribute::id='search_query'][position()=2]`

Comment: For those who got here from Google - the numbering starts from 1 - [1] being the first element and so on

Comment: The word "precedence" may be confusing but [XPath **does** have precedence](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-precedence-order), and using parentheses is an effective way of controlling precedence: "A primary expression may also be created by enclosing any expression in parentheses, which is sometimes helpful in controlling the precedence of operators."

Answer (score 32):

This seems to work:

```
/descendant::input[@id="search_query"][2]
```

I go this from "XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference, 4th Edition" by Michael Kay.

There is also a note in the "Abbreviated Syntax" section of the [XML Path Language specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#abbrev) that provided a clue.

Compare what works:

```
/descendant::input[@id="search_query"][2]
```

to what does **not** work:

```
//input[@id="search_query"][2]
```

The difference is `/descendant::` vs `//`. Consider [what "//" means](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-path-expressions):

> A "//" at the beginning of a path expression is an abbreviation for the initial steps `(fn:root(self::node()) treat as document-node())/descendant-or-self::node()`

And consider [the difference between `descendant` and `descendant-or-self`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#abbrev):

> The path expression `//para[1]` does **not** mean the same as the path expression `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are the first `para` children of their respective parents.

It's probably because the ["context position" changes with `descendant-or-self`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#eval_context) but doesn't change with `descendant`:

> The context position is the position of the context item within the sequence of items currently being processed. It changes whenever the context item changes.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. In my case the accepted solution would not work as I'm using the xpath in robot framework, which wouldn't accept paths starting with brackets. This one however, should do the trick

Comment: When I try this: ${el_my_value}=    XML.Get Element    ${x}    .//isbn

Comment: It leads to this: Multiple elements (6) matching './/isbn' found.
how can I find the 4th?