# XPATH Selecting by position returns incoherent results

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need some help with an issue I can't figure out.

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="prueba.xsl"?>
<ficha>
<titulo></titulo>
<bloque>
    <texto></texto>
    <pregunta id="1" tipo="checkSN">
        <texto>Acredita curso bienestar animal minimo 20 h</texto>
    </pregunta>
    <pregunta id="2" tipo="texto">
        <texto>Sistemática inspección</texto>
    </pregunta>
    <grupo> 
        <texto>trato adecuado enfermos</texto>          
        <pregunta id="3" tipo="desplegableSNP">
            <texto>Recetas correspondientes</texto>
        </pregunta>
        <pregunta id="4" tipo="multiple">
            <texto>Disponen de comida y bebida</texto>
        </pregunta> 
    </grupo>
    <grupo>
        <texto>
            Heridos/Enfermos
        </texto>
        <pregunta id="5" tipo="multiple">
            <texto>Se aprecian heridos o enfermos momento inspeccion</texto>            
        </pregunta>
        <pregunta id="6" tipo="multiple">
            <texto>Separados del resto</texto>          
        </pregunta>
        <pregunta id="7" tipo="multiple">
            <texto>Disponen de comida y bebida</texto>          
        </pregunta>
        <pregunta id="8" tipo="multiple">
            <texto>Disponen de comida y bebida</texto>          
        </pregunta> 
    </grupo>        
</bloque>
<bloque>
    <texto>Condiciones específicas de alojamiento y manejo</texto>  
</bloque>
</ficha>
```

And The folliwng XSL sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prueba.css" />
    </head>
    <body>  
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="/ficha/titulo"/></h2>

  <h3>1: <xsl:value-of select="//pregunta[1]/@id"/></h3>
  <h3>2: <xsl:value-of select="//pregunta[2]/@id"/></h3>
  <h3>3: <xsl:value-of select="//pregunta[3]/@id"/></h3>
  <h3>4: <xsl:value-of select="//pregunta[4]/@id"/></h3>
  <h3>5: <xsl:value-of select="//pregunta[5]/@id"/></h3>
  <h3>6: <xsl:value-of select="//pregunta[6]/@id"/></h3>
  <h3>7: <xsl:value-of select="//pregunta[7]/@id"/></h3>
  <h3>8: <xsl:value-of select="//pregunta[8]/@id"/></h3>
  <h3>c: <xsl:value-of select="count(//pregunta)"/></h3>

     </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I load them I got this result:

1: 1
2: 2
3: 7
4: 8
5:
6:
7:
8:
c: 8

I don't understand why it's ignoring some nodes . If I include new nodes or move them, it always shows 4 results, from node at position 5 to 8 it never shows anything. I need to use this type of selecting because it's from a Java application, the stylesheet is just for testing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath query to get nth instance of an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `//pregunta` in parenthesis. Change your XPath expressions to `(//pregunta)[1]/@id`, `(//pregunta)[2]/@id` ...

Without parenthesis e.g. `//pregunta[4]` evaluates to all `pregunta` elements which are at the fourth position of their parent element.

However (//pregunta)[4] first calculates the sequence of all `pregunta` elements and then takes the fourth element of that sequence.

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot, very well explained, now I understand why it didn't work.

Comment: +1. Right answer. Perhaps save all in variable and use that. Traversing the tree each time is going to be heavy.

Comment: @Kenny, this becomes clearer when you think about the fact that `//` at the beginning of a path expression is equivalent to `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. So `//pregunta[4]` is equivalent to `/descendant-or-self::node()/pregunta[position() = 4]`, in which case it is easier to see how `position()` refers to `pregunta`s position among its direct `pregunta` siblings. Still, this seeming ambiguity makes it hard for me to predict when I don't need parentheses, so I always use them (or a variable, as @empo said).

Answer (score -1):

I can't fully explain why you're seeing the behaviour you are (I suspect it may be something to do with an odd 2d array being returned but that is just my own wild theory) but there does seem to be a simple workaround.  If you use a foreach loop (which seems to fit what you need better anyway, although I could be wrong again!) it returns all of the values from the select, i.e.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//pregunta">
  <h3><xsl:value-of select="position()" /> : <xsl:value-of select="@id" /></h3>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: With the foreach I can select them with no problem, I already use it in other stylesheet. The problem is I need to select them directly by the index in Java using XPath.