# Unable to click the elements in the dynamical list

Tags: selenium, webdriver

For the below code

```
<li class="user ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
   <a id="ui-id-52" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
   <em>User:</em>
       Staff User
   </a>
</li>
```

This is the scenario:

There is a text field, in which I enter the name `Staff`, with that the related values for the staff are displayed in the dynamic list box, in the above scenario the `id` is dynamically generated, and when I tried to select the value by `class`, it is same for all the elements.

I want an `xpath` expression to select the first available options in the list. I tried in many ways like with contains and starts-with, but no use. Please let me know your valuable suggestion.

Thanks in Advance
Shiva.

Comment: Is the html above for the list generated after you enter "Staff" into the text field?

Comment: @Alex Yes the above is the HTML

Comment: Did either of the answers below help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

```
WebElement ele = webdriver.findElement(By.Xpath("//li[@class='user ui-menu-item'][1]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try forming a `List` and then just directly using the first element of that `List`?

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class(contains, 'user')]";
list[0].getText();
```

I'm still not 100% percentage sure what you want to do with the element once you have found it though. It would probably be better to form the `List`, then iterate over that list and perform whatever action you require per `element`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath

```
 "(.//a[@class='ui-corner-all'])[1]"
```

source: [XPath query to get nth instance of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

Use the xpath. It should work

//li[@role = 'presentation']//a[1]