# Test elements to see if they are first-child or second-child with PHP

Tags: php, html, ixmldomelement

If I had this markup:

```
<div class="some-class">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

would it be possible to test, with PHP, if each of the links are the first or second-childs and then assign them classes based on that? I've been looking into the PHP [DOMElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) class but I'm not good enough at PHP to put it into practice.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You may be better off using CSS nth child. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: it would be much easier to use PHP in respect to what I'm working on, which is why I asked if it's possible to use PHP to do this...

Comment: Why don't you use the CSS or JS for this? Edit: Just saw your comment.

Comment: Maybe this will help then. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4008925/212940