# How to select nth element in codeception

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I have a table with checkboxes in each row. The user can select some rows and delete them, also I have this "select all" checkbox. 
I want to test selecting and deleting two rows for example, also click select all and delete them.
So I need to check the second and third checkboxes for the first test and first one for the second test...

I couldn't find a way to select the nth element, the only way I could find is selecting by xpath, so I tried this without luck:

```
$I->checkOption("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[2]");
```

The error is smt. like `//html(//input[@type='checkbox'])[2] is invalid`.
Apparently codeception is modifying the selector, so I tried to use WebDriverBy class but I couldn't find a way to pass it as a parameter...

Any ideas?

PS: This is not the actual case but a simple example to describe the problem...

Comment: Did you try to remove the bracket? "//input[@type='checkbox'][2]"

Comment: @Algiz that won't work since each checkbox is inside a `td` element. I need the brackets unless the checkboxes were siblings...

Comment: As far as I understand XPATH (which could be very tricky), the first part ("//input[@type='checkbox']") will build a list of nodes while the second part ("[2]") will take the second element of the list. It has no notion of sibling. The answer you gave is equivalent to mine. "//input" is a relative XPATH while "/descendant" is an absolute XPATH which will lokk in all nodes.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely tricky :) This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4008925/286619) has a nice explanation of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4008870/286619).
This is it:

```
$I->checkOption("/descendant::input[@type='checkbox'][2]");
```

Answer (score 1):

This works at my end , you can use this one also

$I->checkOption('[name="published"]');

And for the Question:

we can find nth element in following ways:

1. $I->click("table#races-table tbody tr:first-child td:last-child button")- **Table(if you know first child and last child)**
2. $I->click('#side-menu li:nth-child(2)');- **(Side menu you have and need to select item from the sub menu)**
3. $I->selectOption('.radio-tab:nth-child(1)', '1'); -- **(Selecting radio button if you have multiple in a form)**