# How to click the second element when all the attributes are same for an element on the homepage of the application

Tags: android, appium

I am Trying to automate an `android` mobile application which has all same `attributes` i.e. `class` name,`Text`,index.

I need to click the `second` See all button in this `screen` of the application.

The screen shot using the `uiautomator` looks as follows:

There is a see All Link which has the same attributes as the second one

How can i find the element using `findElement(By.name())` or By xpath??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath query to get nth instance of an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple when all attributes has the same name as you say, try to select all elements by `findElements(By.className("...."))` then add `.get(0);` for the first and `.get(1);` for the second this is the logic.

```
findElements(By.className("....")).get(i);
```

> i : the index of the element you want