# XSLFile to select Third tag of XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need Solution for below Task

XML

```
    <core:ReferenceCoded Description="SERTA BUSINESS CARDS"></core:ReferenceCoded>
    <core:ReferenceCoded Description="XM:107008"></core:ReferenceCoded>
    <core:ReferenceCoded Description="J ALMANZA"></core:ReferenceCoded>
    <core:ReferenceCoded Description="847 857 0049"></core:ReferenceCoded>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:template match="abc:BaseItemReference/core:ListOfItemReferences/core:ReferenceCoded"> 

                <xsl:element name="TAG_LINE">                      
                            <xsl:value-of  select="@Description" />                 
                </xsl:element> 

      </xsl:template>
```

The output XML File is

```
< TAG_LINE>SERTA BUSINESS CARDS</TAG_LINE>
  < TAG_LINE>XM:107008</TAG_LINE>
  < TAG_LINE>J ALMANZA</TAG_LINE>
  < TAG_LINE>847 857 0049</TAG_LINE>
```

I need output of third Line. Please Suggest on changing the XSL file Code to fetch data in the Format

```
<TAG_LINE>J ALMANZA</TAG_LINE>
```

Comment: Output to be <TAG_LINE>J ALMANZA</TAG_LINE>

Comment: Put your required output **in the question** please

Comment: @MattJones I need Third TAG_LINE alone.

Comment: <TAG_LINE>J ALMANZA</TAG_LINE>

Comment: Put your required output **IN THE QUESTION**

Comment: Also, you XML is incomplete - please make your XML **a correctly valid example** of your input. I'm not going to spend time making up what I think you're using if you don't put it in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath query to get nth instance of an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)

Comment: XML file is too long to be posted here. Is Their any otherway I can give it to you. I am new to the stack interface to post a question

Comment: This is XML - you can make a **small example**. Your XPath shows only 2 parent nodes, so **MAKE A SMALL EXAMPLE**. I've guessed at your XML and given you a solution but you could have found this by googling it. It doesn't look like you understand XML or XSLT so please go and spend some time reading about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the output you want:

```
<xsl:template match="abc:BaseItemReference/core:ListOfItemReferences/core:ReferenceCoded[3]">
    <xsl:element name="TAG_LINE">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```