# How to target a specific <table> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to target the highlighted "table" of an html to scrape on. However my issue here is that there is now specific `id` or `class` to target it on.

[image]

Is there a way to target that specific table?

Comment: Is there a specific order? Ie is it always the 3rd table? If yes, have a look at XPath ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)). You can do something similar with JS too...

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: If it has some order: document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

Comment: @urban — Why XPath? You can target third of type with CSS selectors.

Comment: I'm targeting the 3rd <table> tag

Comment: @Quentin true, there are few approaches out there, but I assume the OP wants to parse someone else's page (else he could assign a distinct class or something)... was thinking `wget` like scrapers + xpath... Both CSS and JS would work in `phantomjs` or similar parsers that load the page

Comment: @urban — The question *was* tagged [tag:css]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm targeting the 3rd `<table>` tag

You should use the [`nth-of-type` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo).

```
table:nth-of-type(3) {}
```

---

Re edit.

Previously you were asking about CSS, but you've changed the tags on the question and are now asking about JavaScript. You can still use a selector:

```
document.querySelector("table:nth-of-type(3)")
```

… but you may see more support for the simple [`getElementsByTagName` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[2]; // 0 indexed
```

Comment: Thanks! I the `table:nth-of-type(3)` to work on a scraper library (x-ray).

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('MsoNormalTable');
```

To filter on a specific ID use:

```
document.getElementById('id');
```

For more information visit this:
[Explanation document.getElementByClassName();](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: There are multiple tables with that class name in the picture

Comment: @Quentin Maybe it will still help him? adding Javascript isn't that hard. And this is what he is looking for. He can even filter out the first table by doing document.getElementsByClassName('MsoNormalTable')[0];

Comment: @Quentin He also changed it from CSS to Javascript so my awnser could indeed be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it will always be in the same position, you can use the [`table:nth-of-type(3)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) selector in CSS, which will select the third element of type `table`.

```
table:nth-of-type(3) {
    color: red;
}
```

In JavaScript you would use: `document.querySelectorAll('table')[2]` to select the third (arrays begin indexing at `0`) element of type `table` on the page.

Answer (score -1):

if your target table always last in parent you can use ::last-of-type

```
.wordSelection1 table:last-ot-type{border: 1px solid red;}
```