# Unable to get partial or wildcard equivalent xpath selector

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get these 6 selectors.  I am only able to get 8 it seems.  Furthermore, it is dynamic so it keeps changing

```
//div[@class='sm-CouponLink']//div[@class='sm-CouponLink_Label']
```

The page keeps changing to

```
//div[@class='sm-Coupon']//div[@class='sm-CouponLink']
```

And other variations of that.

Ideally something like  `//div[@class*='sm-Coup']`
I’ve tried using a wildcard but I’m fairly certain using that xpath does not support this and I am not wanting to use CSS in this case as I am fairly reliant on it.
I have also tried:

```
//div[starts-with(@class, ''sm-Coupo')]
```

I am on this page here:

https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/

[image]

Comment: Scraping that site, and many sites with data, is against their ToS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xpath:

```
//div[starts-with(@class, 'sm-CouponLink_Label')]
//div[contains(@class, 'sm-CouponLink_Label')]

//div[@class='sm-CouponLink']/div[starts-with(@class, 'sm-CouponLink_Label')]
```

Or XPath if you need wrapper div:

```
//div[@class='sm-CouponLink'][div[starts-with(@class, 'sm-CouponLink_Label')]]
```

Or CSS:

```
div.sm-CouponLink>div[class^='sm-CouponLink_Label']
```

PS: you xpath `//div[starts-with(@class, ''sm-Coupo')]` is almost correct, except that it has extra `'` quote. Here is the valid one:
`//div[starts-with(@class, 'sm-Coupo')]`

Comment: Thanks.  The xpath worked and then I think the webpage changed (very dynamic page).  Is there a nth-child equivalent for xpath something like .sm-CouponLink_Label:nth-child(1).  This page is very dynamic so trying to keep xpath small

Comment: n-th element in xpath: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element

Comment: I have something like: //div[starts-with(@class, 'sm-Coupo')][1]  .  Not really ideal, I may have to find some tutorials on better getting xpaths