# Selenium c# click exacly span 1 by xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

All i want is to just click exacly span 1

Example let's go to youtube.com , then write something in searcher and finally click 1st span like this:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://youtube.com");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='search']")).SendKeys("I should be so lucky");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='search']")).SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

And now i want click 1st link but this path :

```
//*[@id="description-text"]/span
```

show us 19 links . How can i write span 1?
I try something liek this

```
//*[@id="description-text"]/span[1]
```

but this doesn't works.
Can somene heelp how to choose exacly only 1 span by changing this xpath?

Comment: this xpath just is for 19 links on youtube  i want just choose just 1st or 2nd or third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
(//[@id="description-text"]/span)[1]

REF :[XPath query to get nth instance of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)

Hope this helps

Comment: that's exacly what i'm looking for - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would store all items in List and iterate upon will, like so:

```
List<WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.id("description-text"));
```

than You can do following, or itterate all items with for each loop:

```
for (WebElement element :listItems) {
            //... do whatever You need to do with element
            element.findElements(By.tagName("span")); // so this is Your span, or all spans 
        }
```

or select certain element:

```
WebElement element = listItems.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("span"));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **Xpath** :

```
//h3[contains(@class,'ytd-video-renderer')]/a[contains(@aria-label,'Kylie Minogue - I Should Be So Lucky by HCAESAR 10 years ago ')]
```

You can use this code :

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[id='search-input']>input")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='search-input']>input")).sendKeys("I should be so lucky"+Keys.RETURN);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("primary")));
WebElement links =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//h3[contains(@class,'ytd-video-renderer')]/a[contains(@aria-label,'Kylie Minogue - I Should Be So Lucky by HCAESAR 10 years ago ')]")));
links.click();
```