# Robot Framework(SeleniumLibrary) - Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to automate a certain web page that has dropdown lists and I'm facing issue with one of the dropdown list.

Robot script:

```
Input Text    //*[@id="description"]    Test Attribute Robot
Click Element    //*[@id="short_description"]    
Select From List By Label    //*[@id="entity_id"]    Location
Select From List By Label    //*[@id="format_id"]    Value List    
Select From List By Label    //*[@id="status_id"]    Active
```

HTML:

```
<select nextfocus="" enterindex="2" select-dropdown="" name="entity_id" id="entity_id" ng-options="entity.id as entity.entity for entity in attributeCtrl.Entities" ng-model="attributeCtrl.Attribute.entity_id" class="form-control select-component input-sm ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-valdr-required ng-valid-valdr-digits ng-invalid-valdr ng-invalid-required" required=""><option value="" disabled="" class="" selected="selected">Select Entity</option>
<option label="Location" value="number:1">Location</option>
<option label="Item" value="number:7">Item</option>
<option label="Vendor" value="number:23">Vendor</option>
<option label="Made To Orders" value="number:314">Made To Orders</option></select>

<select nextfocus="" enterindex="3" name="status_id" id="status_id" ng-options="status.code as status.description for status in attributeCtrl.Status" ng-model="attributeCtrl.Attribute.status_id" class="form-control select-component input-sm ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-valdr-required ng-valid-valdr-digits ng-invalid-valdr ng-invalid-required" required="">
<option value="" disabled="" class="" selected="selected">Select Status</option>
<option label="Pending" value="number:100">Pending</option>
<option label="Active" value="number:200">Active</option>
<option label="Inactive" value="number:300">Inactive</option>
<option label="Discontinued" value="number:400">Discontinued</option></select>
```

The issue is with the last dropdown list. It throws an error

> ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated.

However, the other dropdowns get selected successfully.

Also, if the id of the element is changed to ***"statusId"*** instead of ***"status_id"*** it works fine.

I've tried "Select From List By Value" keyword as well but that results in the same error.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Can you add the HTML for the relevant dropdown?

Comment: I've added the HTML code for the dropdown list with the issue and the other that works fine. Would this be sufficient?

Comment: Perhaps you have more than one item on the page with the id `status_id`.

Comment: @BryanOakley, There are indeed 2 drop down lists with the same id(select_id) and I hadn't noticed this until you mentioned. What could I do to specify which drop-down to access?

Comment: ids should be unique. The best solution is to modify the code to make sure the id is unique.

Comment: This too is a solvable problem. In this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4008925/6152737) you'll find some suggestions on how to do this with xpath.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley and Kootstra for your inputs. Now that I know the problem and possible solutions I think I can sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Set Focus To Element    //*[@id="status_id"]
Select From List By Label    //*[@id="status_id"]    Active
```