# How to count nested div using selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
<div class="bodyCells">
      <div style="position:absolute;left:0;">
         <div style="overflow:hidden;">
            <div title="AAA" class="pivotTableCellWrap">AAA</div>
            <div title="BBB" class="pivotTableCellWrap">BBB</div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div title="AAA-123" class="pivotTableCellWrap">AAA-123</div>
            <div title="BBB-123" class="pivotTableCellWrap">BBB-123</div>        
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I have two bodycells div in my page and I want the count the nested div inside the second one.
**Required output** :-  I want the count=2

**Tried Approach**  :-

```
int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='bodyCells[2]']//div").Count());
Console.WriteLine(rowCount);
```

Comment: I had two div of bodycells in my code ..I want the count of nested div for second one as I mentioned above

Comment: Ya it should be outside ..but I still need correct command for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath query to get nth instance of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)

Comment: int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@id='bodyCells'])[2]/div/div").Count());
Console.WriteLine(rowCount);  Is this will work

Comment: You can use a CSS selector like, `div[title$='-123']`, which will find `DIV`s that have a title that ends with "-123". That's less brittle than your approach in case other elements get added to the list and the index changes. See [CSS selector reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview).

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided *to count the nested child `<divs>` inside the second (parent) `<div>`* you can use either of the following solution:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  List<string> elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.bodyCells div.pivotTableCellWrap[title*='-']"));
  Console.WriteLine(elements.Count);
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  List<string> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='bodyCells']//div[@class='pivotTableCellWrap' and contains(@title,'-')]"));
  Console.WriteLine(elements.Count);
  ```

Comment: @jatinpatware Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.bodyCells div.pivotTableCellWrap[title*='-']")).Count;
    Console.WriteLine(rowCount); is working properly syntactically but logically not giving correct output

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below modified XPath inorder to get the count of second nested div

**XPath:** `//div[@class='bodyCells']/div/div[2]/div`

**Code:**

```
var rowCount = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='bodyCells']/div/div[2]/div")).Count;
Console.WriteLine(rowCount);
```