# how to locate specific node for Xpath on index basis?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I do need to locate second node, on basic of same class available in the Table.

There are six results found on webpage, for query : `//td[@class='checkboxCollumn']`

[image]

If I locate it for second node, By using `//td[@class='checkboxCollumn'][2]` its giving 0 result.

I have tried some other variations : `//td[@class='checkboxCollumn']//i[2]` and so on its giving 0 result.

[image]

What is the correct way to locate it with index ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath query to get nth instance of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to locate like this

```
(//td[@class='checkboxCollumn'])[2]
```

Comment: @IshitaShah  Okay sure. @Gaurav solution is correct as well but he missed out the `()`, for an example, try out `(//td[@class='checkboxCollumn'])[position()=2]`

Comment: Without round bracket is there any other syntax ? I need to use it on multiple combine xpaths, Which is defined as String.

Comment: @IshitaShah I use the wrapper called WATIR which sits on the Ruby Selenium Binding where I don't need to write xpath,for an example, for the above expression I would write, `b.tds(class: "checkboxCollumn").last.click`

Comment: Ya, Above is working for 1 one of the solution. And need to use of 2nd requirement, But its not working on combination requirement. Please suggest if there is any other way.

Comment: My requirement is same,  http://prntscr.com/kmbokf but both xpath are defined separately. So I can't include round brackets on any.

Comment: @IshitaShah I did not get your point actually, perhaps you may create a new question,somebody may come along your way

Answer (score 0):

Use this.. to locate second node...

```
(//td[@class='checkboxCollumn'])[position()=2]
```

Here **position() is 1-indexed** i.e. position will start counting from 1

Comment: You have missed out `()` `(//td[@class='checkboxCollumn'])[position()=2]`

Comment: @Rajagopalan, thanks! for pointing silly mistake, updated answer accordingly

Comment: Without round bracket is there any other syntax ? I need to use it on multiple combine xpaths, Which is defined as String.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`(//td[@class='checkboxCollumn'])[2]`

With this:
`//td[@class='checkboxCollumn'][2]` you trying to match second element within the same container

Answer (score 0):

try using the 
(//td[@class='checkboxCollumn'])[2]
as [] has higher priority over //.So rememeber to put the expression is brackets when need to specify the exact node of the selected node-list.

In ur case,it will search for all the elements in the document,that are at the second place.
Even though above thing not work,let me know.

Comment: It has nothing to do with *"priority"*. Also note that the same solution has been already provided 3 times and your makes no improvements