# Finding second table using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to identify the second table using HTMLAgilityPack

```
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<td>0-A</td> <td>&nbsp|&nbsp;</td>
<td>B</td> <td>&nbsp|&nbsp;</td>
<td>C</td> <td>&nbsp|&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
<br><br>
<TABLE DIR=LTR BORDER>
<TR>
<TD DIR=LTR ALIGN=RIGHT><b>A</b></TD>
<TD DIR=LTR ALIGN=LEFT><b>B</b></TD>
<TD DIR=LTR ALIGN=LEFT><b>C</b></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

I have tried

```
Dim table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]")
```

and that does not work.  I have tried it as a capital and that does not work.  If I put "//table[1]" I do find the first table.  Is there a different way that I should do this?  I'm doing this in VB.net

Additional information when I do

```
 For Each x_table As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")
```

it finds two tables and I can skip the first and work on the second, but is that the way it was designed to work?

Comment: Does `(//table)[2]` work? (From [XPath query to get nth instance of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4008925/1115360).)

Comment: You can use SelectNodes and then use the indexer: Dim table2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")(2);

Comment: doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")(1) worked for the second table-- and (0) for the first.  Thanks   (//table)[2] would not compile in VB