# How to get text in span with xpath. selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

Before asking, I find answer through google for 2hours. But there's no answer for me.

I use selenium with python

I apply below q/a answer to my code but nothing text printed.

[XPath query to get nth instance of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element/4008925)

**What I want to get is "Can't select"**

```
<li data-index="5" date="20190328" class="day dimmed">
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
        <span class="dayweek">Tuesday</span>
        <span class="day">28</span>
        <span class="sreader">Can't select</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**I use xpath because I need to repeat**

**I should do this. 
The HTML code above is a simple change**

```
day_lists = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li')
```

**Nothing printed and there's no error**

```
for day_list in day_lists:
    print(day_list.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="sreader"]').text)
```

++++ 2019/3/24/16:45(+09:00)

**When I test with below code**

`print(day_list.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="sreader"]/text()'))`

**Error comes out. Why there's no such element?**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":".//span[@class="sreader"]/text()"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *nothing printed and there's no error* then required text might be hidden or not generated yet.

For first case you might need to use `get_attribute('textContent')`:

```
day_lists = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
for day_list in day_lists:
    print(day_list.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="sreader"]').get_attribute('textContent'))
```

For second case:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

day_lists = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
for day_list in day_lists:
    print(wait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: day_list.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="sreader"]').text)
```

Note that in both cases you need to add leading dot in XPath:

```
'//span' --> './/span'
```

Comment: I test `<a href` code if list did not loaded, but working well. And What you say case1, case2 also result nothing,

Comment: hmm... for me those `span` nodes really appears as empty: `<span class="sreader"></span>`. I see no text. It seem that you need to select (click on) date to generate `"선택불가"` text...

Comment: I always check after click... Thank you

Comment: Finally this worked! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To print the desired text e.g. **선택불가** from the `<span>` tag you can write a function as follows:

```
def print_text(my_date):
        print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='day dimmed'][@date='" +my_date+ "']//span[@class='sreader']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Now you can call the function with any date as follows:

```
print_text("20190328")
```

Comment: I want to use **day_list**.
 `day_list.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="sreader"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')` result same

Comment: `day_list.find_element_by_xpath('///li[@date="'+day_list.get_attribute('date')+'"]//span[@class="sreader"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')` this also result same. nothing printed

Answer (score 0):

Here are the solutions. If this does not work then I predict the element might present either in separate window or frame.

**CSS:**
    li[class='day dimmed'][date='20190328'] .sreader
[image]

**xpath:**

[image]

To check if there are multiple windows use below

```
print(len(driver.window_handles))
```

To check if there are multiple frames use below

```
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('iframe')))
```

Comment: `day_list.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` act, But Why `print(day_list.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="sreader"]').text)` print nothing? I also checked UTF8, that's not problem

Comment: And I can't use `driver.` Why I use day_list is I use this stie "http://www.cgv.co.kr/ticket/". My question is nothing to do with this all code. Because I changed some code. So Anyway I should use `day_list.`

Comment: `.get_attribute('innerText')` result same, nothing printed

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options:

```
day_lists=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//li[@class="day dimmed"]')))
for day_list in day_lists:
    print(day_list.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="sreader"]').text)
```

OR

```
day_lists=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//li[@class="day dimmed"]')))
for day_list in day_lists:
   print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", day_list.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="sreader"]')))
```

Please note that you need following imports as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: both print nothing. I attached some code at main text. Can you check them?