# php read html and handle double id-appearance

Tags: php, html, parsing, get

For my project I'm reading an external website which has used the same ID twice. I can't change that.

I need the content from the second appearance of that ID but my code just results the first one and does not see the second one.
Also a count to `$data` results 1 but not 2.
I'm desperate. Does anyone have an idea how to access the second ID 'hours'?

```
<?PHP
  $url = 'myurl';
  $contents = file_get_contents($url);
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
  $data = $dom->getElementById("hours");
  echo $data->nodeValue."\n";
  echo count($data);
?>
```

Comment: `getElementById` always returns a single node. PHP's DOMDocument does not provide a method to get multiple nodes by their `id` attribute, but you could probably write a query using [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rickdenhaan points out, [`getElementById`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) always returns a single element which is the first element that has that specific value of `id`. However you can use [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to find all nodes which have a given `id` value and then pick out the one you want (in this code it will find the second one):

```
$url = 'myurl';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$count = 0;
foreach ($xpath->query("//*[@id='hours']") as $node) {
    if ($count == 1) echo $node->nodeValue;
    $count++;
}
```

As @NigelRen points out in the comments, you can simplify this further by directly selecting the second input in the XPath i.e.

```
$node = $xpath->query("(//*[@id='hours'])[2]")[0];
echo $node->nodeValue;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fCr6o)

Comment: You could shorten it slightly by using XPath to only fetch the second item - `$node = $xpath->query("(//*[@id='hours'])[2]")[0];` and `echo $node->nodeValue;` - have a look through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for that reference. That does make it simpler, I've updated the answer with that alternative.