# Selenium, get text from the nth same tag

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get the span text for `fourth class` from the following html base for a specific nth iteration of that class in the html base.

```
<ul class="first_class">
    <li class="second_class ">
        <span class="third_class">
            <span class="fourth_class">100</span> 
        " temp_x"</span>
    </li>
    <li class="second_class ">
        <span class="third_class">
            <span class="fourth_class" title="200">200</span>
        " temp_y"</span>
        </li>
    <li class="second_class ">
        <span class="third_class">
            <span class="fourth_class">300</span>
        " temp_z"</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to specifically grab the 2nd and 3rd iteration so the output is `200` and `300`

I'm only able to retrieve `100` which is from the first iteration using this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='fourth class']").text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the nth css selector. Also available with xpath

See this similar question for an example [XPath query to get nth instance of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)

Comment: I tried the method you mentioned, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here are the to statements I tried, `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='fourth_class ']")[1].text` and even `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='second_class ']")[1].text`. Both result in `'WebElement' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: What you want to modify is the xpath, not the result from find_element_by_xpath. Try self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//li[@class='fourth_class '])[2]").text

Comment: `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//li[@class='fourth_class '])[2]"}` Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='fourth_class '])[2]").text` changing `li` to `span` seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Ah yes, it would need to be span as that is the element with the class "fourth_class"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting the count of your locator using findElements. once you get count, you can traverse through loop using your xpath in the way.

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='fourth class']");
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='fourth_class'])[i]").text;
}
```