# cppcheck generates wrong xml structure

Tags: c++, c, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I am trying to parse the XML data from the output of cppcheck. But the XML structure seems wrong.

```
cppcheck src --enable=warning,style,unusedFunction --xml --inconclusive --std=posix --std=c++11 2> error_s.xml
```

cppcheck XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results version="2">
    <cppcheck version="1.82"/>
    <errors>
        <error id="funcArgNamesDifferent" severity="style" msg="Blah Blah bLah." verbose="Blah Blah Verbose" cwe="628" inconclusive="true">
            <location file="src/DataLayer/ABC.cpp" line="329"/>
            <location file0="src/DataLayer/ABC.cpp" file="src/DataLayer/ABC.h" line="64"/>
            <location file0="src/DataLayer/ABC.cpp" file="src/DataLayer/ABC.h" line="64"/>
            <location file0="src/DataLayer/ABC.cpp" file="src/DataLayer/ABC.h" line="64"/>
        </error>
</errors>
</results>
```

Shouldn't the `location` node be inside an array like `locations`?

```
        <locations>
            <location file="src/DataLayer/ABC.cpp" line="329"/>
            <location file0="src/DataLayer/ABC.cpp" file="src/DataLayer/ABC.h" line="64"/>
        </locations>
```

Comment: I tested your posted XML with a few online XML validators and they all said it was perfectly fine.

Comment: yea because it checks for basic validation ... but how do you get the value of second location node..? for ex: in php if i do ```$cpp_error['location']``` -> it points to first location then it produces warning.

Comment: @Hahn have you tried `$cpp_error['location'][2]`? I don't see the need for a `locations` array. You would have the same problem accessing the second `location` within that `locations` array. You need something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately it cannot be accessed with out writting too many if-statements ..

```
if(isset($location)){

}
```

[Conversation with CppChecker Developer..](https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/general/thread/1b26222530/#e6d2)  Hopefully it would get fixed when they release v3

for now, the only way to access is using too many if-Statements.

if not, there is also library [htmlreport](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/tree/main/htmlreport) which will generate html pages..