# Protractor get the second element of an ocurrence

Tags: selenium, testing, xpath, automated-tests, protractor

I have an issue and I'm quite new with protractor.

I need to get an element by its text, right now it is not possible to change how the UI is built to use better selectors.

So what I have right now is a `span` tag with the text `Summary` inside of it, to retrieve the element using XPath I do the following:

```
const myElement = element(by.xpath("//span[text()='Summary']"));
```

That works for the first occurrence when there's only one element on the screen, however, when there are two elements, it fails with the following error:

> - Failed: element not interactable

Possibly because it is trying to access the first element which is toggled.
So I tried accessing the element index as I read around with:

```
element(by.xpath("//span[text()='Summary']")[1]);
```

And got the following error:

> Failed: Invalid locator

I read somewhere that the values start on 1 and not on 0 so I tried with:

```
element(by.xpath("//span[text()='Summary']")[2]);
```

Yet, I'm still getting the same error:

> Failed: Invalid locator

Is there a way I can get to these second element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using list slicing then there exist more then one elements. So you can try to use elements instead of element

```
element(by.xpath("(//span[text()='Summary'])[2]");
```

OR

```
element(by.xpath("(//span[contains(text(),'Summary')])[2]");
```

Comment: that unfortunately gives the following error: Failed: elements is not defined

Comment: @Danny22  Please,see  the  updated answer

Comment: Now it actually worked, would you mind updating the first paragraph too to explain your proposal and not elements, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this XPath, it has additional brackets, you have been almost there.

`(//span[text()='Summary'])[2]`

Reference:
[XPath query to get nth instance of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)