# whats the diff between the xpaths: (//a[@class="_2whKao"])[3] and //a[@class="_2whKao"][3]

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpathsapply

Im getting 1 match with the fist xpath but 0 with the latter

I tried extracting an anchor tag using selenium by xpaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### DIFFERENCE:

*(//a[@class="_2whKao"])[3]* - This expression tries to locate the 3rd element(from the top) in the DOM.

*//a[@class="_2whKao"][3]* - This expression tries to locate the element(s) who are the 3rd child of their parent node.

Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4008925/7598774